# Display of a dialog window

Tags: visualforce, pagemessages, popup-window

I'd like to know how to display a dialog or pop-up window in Salesforce.

I'm overriding the standard convert button by using associated custom visualforce page.

I use the custom visualfoce page to invoke an appex controller class.

Depending on the given parameters to the appex class the end result of the class is to return a message.

The message is displayed in a visualforce page(see the attached screenshot)[image]

What I would like to know is how to dispaly a message in a dialog or a pop-up window instead of a visualforce page.

Here is what I would like to achive:
Once the convert button is pressed(see the attached screenshot)[image]
I would like to know how to dispaly the message in a dialog or a pop-up window.

Could you please advise how this can be achieved?

Comment: Use a javascript button to check the values, if fail, present alert message, if pass direct to VF URL or do whatever you need to. NOTE: If you are using lightning the button will not be available for use there since LEX does not support JS buttons

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Instead of creating and using new javascript button can you suggest a different approach to help me display the message in the first sreenshot in a pop-up window?

Comment: I was thinking of saving the message in a custom field and use javascript to read and display the message. Although I'm not sure if this can work and be easy to implement.